# Flask WTForms BooleanField UnboundField

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I am writing a script that normally retrieves 5 lines from the database and I want to display it as a checkbox list.

But it doesn't display correctly: it says " UnboundField "

**form.py**

```
class ExampleForm(FlaskForm):
    [...query & results...]
    for line in results_sql:
        list_checkbox[line.label] = BooleanField(line.label)
```

**routes.py**

```
@bp.route('/example')
def example():
    form = ExampleForm()
    return render_template("index.html", form=form)
```

**index.html**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
    {% for checkbox in form.list_checkbox %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ checkbox }}</td>
        <td>{{ form.list_checkbox[checkbox ] }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Result:

[image: rendered table]

Comment: You are not showing us how the `list_checkbox` mapping is related to `ExampleForm`. How do the `BooleanField` instances get added to the form, exactly?

Comment: Well, I imagine that's missing, but I don't retrieve somes explanations for this. Can you show me a link or a brief explanation ? Thank you

Comment: Right, I've edited your code to at least make the dictionary a part of the form here.

Answer (score 3):

You've put your fields inside a nested dictionary. The form can't bind such fields as it can't handle arbitrary containers.

Instead, you need to put the fields in a [field enclosure](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fields.html#field-enclosures). I'd use a [`FormField()` field](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fields.html#wtforms.fields.FormField) to point to a nested `Form` class. You can generate the nested `Form` class by calling the [`BaseForm()` constructor](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/forms.html#wtforms.form.BaseForm):

> What *BaseForm* provides is a container for a collection of fields, **which it will bind at instantiation**, and hold in an internal dict. Dict-style access on a BaseForm instance will allow you to access (and modify) the enclosed fields.

Then, when you create an instance of your `ExampleForm()` class, it'll bind the `FormField` field, which then in turn creates an instance of the nested form object, which then binds each of the fields you gave `BaseForm()`

Because calling `BaseForm(fields)` will create a form *instance*, you do need to wrap that in a function first before you can use it as a nested form:

```
def form_from_fields(fields):
    def create_form(prefix='', **kwargs):
        form = BaseForm(fields, prefix=prefix, meta=FlaskForm.Meta)
        form.process(**kwargs)
        return form
    return create_form

class ExampleForm(FlaskForm):
    # ...

    list_checkbox = FormField(
        form_from_fields(
            [(line.label, BooleanField(line.label)) for line in results_sql]
        )
    )
```

`BaseForm()` doesn't take any data like a `Form` class would, so you need to pass the parameters that `FormField()` passes into create an instance to the `.process()` method before returning the instance.

When iterating over the `list_checkbox` field when rendering, you get the fields directly and you get the label from the field object:

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
    {% for checkbox in form.list_checkbox %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ checkbox.label }}</td>
        <td>{{ checkbox }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Demo (using the base WTForms library, but the Flask-WTF process is the same):

```
>>> from wtforms.form import BaseForm, Form
>>> from wtforms.fields import BooleanField, FormField
>>> fields = ['Calendrier', 'Commentaire', 'Dessin', 'Ex-libris', 'Gravure']
>>> def form_from_fields(fields):
...     def create_form(prefix='', **kwargs):
...         form = BaseForm(fields, prefix=prefix)
...         form.process(**kwargs)
...         return form
...     return create_form
...
>>> class ExampleForm(Form):
...     list_checkbox = FormField(form_from_fields([(field, BooleanField(field)) for field in fields]))
...
>>> form = ExampleForm()
>>> form.list_checkbox
<wtforms.fields.core.FormField object at 0x1232a76d8>
>>> list(form.list_checkbox)
[<wtforms.fields.core.BooleanField object at 0x1232a77f0>, <wtforms.fields.core.BooleanField object at 0x1232a78d0>, <wtforms.fields.core.BooleanField object at 0x1232a7978>, <wtforms.fields.core.BooleanField object at 0x1232a7a20>, <wtforms.fields.core.BooleanField object at 0x1232a7ac8>]
>>> print(*form.list_checkbox, sep='\n')
<input id="list_checkbox-Calendrier" name="list_checkbox-Calendrier" type="checkbox" value="y">
<input id="list_checkbox-Commentaire" name="list_checkbox-Commentaire" type="checkbox" value="y">
<input id="list_checkbox-Dessin" name="list_checkbox-Dessin" type="checkbox" value="y">
<input id="list_checkbox-Ex-libris" name="list_checkbox-Ex-libris" type="checkbox" value="y">
<input id="list_checkbox-Gravure" name="list_checkbox-Gravure" type="checkbox" value="y">
```

The `FormField()` field then also makes sure that you can set default values for your form, or that you can then access the data set when the form is posted again:

```
>>> form = ExampleForm(list_checkbox={'Calendrier': True})
>>> print(form.list_checkbox['Calendrier'])
<input checked id="list_checkbox-Calendrier" name="list_checkbox-Calendrier" type="checkbox" value="y">
>>> print(form.list_checkbox['Commentaire'])
<input id="list_checkbox-Commentaire" name="list_checkbox-Commentaire" type="checkbox" value="y">
```